# Iterator<T> from istream, unformatted extraction

Tags: c++, c++11

I need an iterator over elements of type `T` from a `std::istream`, where `T` is an integer type.

Is there any way to do it which does not involve intermediate copies to a vector?

**More details on what I'm trying to achieve**

What I want is to conceptually "cast" the input stream as the serialization of an array of elements of type `T` and iterate through them.

Something like this:

```
std::vector<int> v {{ 1, 2, 3 }};
char *v_start = reinterpret_cast<char*>(v.data());
std::string v_s(v_start, v.size() * sizeof(v[0]); // v as a string
std::stringstream s_s(v_s); // serialized array of T = int
my_iterator<int> v_begin(s_s), v_end; // What I want
std::vector<int> v_copy(v_begin, v_end); // Now v_copy is the same as v
```

This is what I tried:

```
template <typename T>
std::tuple<std::istreambuf_iterator<T>, std::istreambuf_iterator<T>>
get_iterator(std::istream &s)
{
        return std::make_tuple(
                std::istreambuf_iterator<T>(s),
                std::istreambuf_iterator<T>{}
        );
}
```

unfortunately it does not compile because `std::istreambuf_iterator<T>` (notice the "buf" in the name) can be constructed only from a `std::basic_istream<T>`, and what I have is a `std::basic_istream<char>`.

I also tried using a `std::istream_iterator<T>`, but unfortunately it performs **formatted** extraction, that is, it extracts elements by using `operator<<`, which is very different than extracting elements of type `T` by performing raw `read` invocations.

Comment: The T in basic_istream isn't about the objects you pull out, it's about the underlying character type of the text.

Comment: _"Is there any way to do it which does not involve intermediate copies?"_ You can't copy streams in the first place. And, most likely, you're using streams wrong.

Comment: @black By "copying" I mean dumping a stream into a vector.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: yes, but the point is I don't know what the underlying type is until deep inside my function. What I need is an equivalent of void* for streams. Is there something like this?

Comment: Do you mean you have a vector of streams, or a vector of integers and you want to read integers from the stream into the vector? If the latter, then I suggest you read about [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Comment: For that there's `istream_iterator<T>`. Could you provide a pseudo-code of what you are trying to achieve? As it currently stands the answer is "no" because streams work with characters; you probably want to do something else.

Comment: @black: this is what I'd like to achieve:

http://pastebin.com/UpCALhSB

That is, convert my stream to an `istream_iterator<T>` once I found out what's the real underlying type of the stream.

Comment: The `std::istreambuf_iterator<cT>` iterators are for use with the stream's character type `cT`. Streams always travel in terms of one character type and converting between streams with different character types is generally not what is needed. If you want to extract formatted values you want `std::istream_iterator<T>` (not the absence of `buf`).

Comment: I think the bigger problem is finding out the "real underlying type", in combination with templates. C++ is a statically compiled language, which means that it has no run-time type-introspection or reflection. So you can't create new instances of a template class at run-time unless you know the type at compile-time, since templates are a pure compile-time concept.

Comment: Ok, i explain better what I'm trying to achieve. The user hands in a serialized index (as a stream) and some satellite data. The satellite data is a sequence of values of type T, but T depends on the index, so the user can't pass a stream over T. I'd like to support this behaviour while maintaining the flexibility of streams (so the satellite data can be stored and accessed however the user wants to).

Comment: @akappa: I meant in your answer, so that every reader (you and I included) can immediately understand what you're asking _without going through the comments_. As I've already told you, the answer is currently no; therefore, edit _your question_ explaining in detail your problem and how you'd solve it so that other solution, likely better tailored for you problem, can be proposed as well.

Comment: Streams are not in terms of any arbitrary type. Streams are in terms of character types. Although the IOStreams library is templated on the character type viable alternatives are really `char` and `wchar_t` (you can create streams for other character types but altough I know what needs to do it would probably take me a day or so per character types; potential alternate types could be `char16_t` and `char32_t`). If you want stream support, you'll need to serialize/deserialize the objects from the sequence of characters. The stream type won't change, though.

Comment: Thank you Dietmar. I think I'll write a custom iterator for extracting elements of type T from the istream.

Comment: You might have a look at `std::wbuffer_convert`, but without more information about what you’re trying to do, I can’t give a more complete answer.

Comment: Even from the edit, it's hard to answer because code is supposed to solve a problem and yours is hard to even try to grasp. If you don't know the data you're handling, then you can't solve your problem. You'd probably better off reanalyze your problem in order to get a clear view of the data it handles. Then we can talk about code. At least for me, IMHO.

Comment: The problem is: the library knows what's the type T, but the user can't, so I need a kind of "void*" stream (passed by the user) which can be "recast" to T (by the library) when needed. I know it sounds weird, but in my problem is makes perfectly sense :)

Answer (score 0):

As [@Dietmar Kuhl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120273/dietmar-k%c3%bchl) pointed out in the comments,  if you want to extract formatted values you want `std::istream_iterator<T>` not `std::istreambuf_iterator<T>`. Furthermore, you don't need a `tuple` but a `pair`:

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<std::istream_iterator<T>, std::istream_iterator<T>>
get_iterator(std::istream &s) {
  return std::make_pair(std::istream_iterator<T>(s), std::istream_iterator<T>{});
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/871d53b0e33c3064)

Comment: Unfortunately what I want is *unformatted* extraction, that's why I switched over `istreambuf_iterator`